# Hiding a element, when an input field is empty

Tags: jquery

So my selector with .username in it is the input field, and i would like it to run the $('#status div').hide(); when the input has no value, like if people wrote something and deleted what they wrote i would like it to hide the status div. I'm really not sure on what would be the best way to do that, would be nice with some help!

Here's the code i have done so far:

```
    $('.username').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            'url': 'api/username/',
            'type': 'post',
            'data': {'username': $('.username').val()},
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.available) {
                    showStatus(0);
                } else {
                    showStatus(1);
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                showStatus(2);
            },
            complete: function(data) {
                console.log('complete');
            }
        });
    } else {
        showStatus(0);
    }
});

function showStatus(id) {
    $('#status div').hide();
    $($('#status div')[id]).show();
}
```

I've tried something like

```
if($(".username").val()){
    $('#status div').hide();
}
```

but it does not work

If you feel like i haven't explained myself good enough feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.length > 0` test is already checking for an empty input. Put what you want in the `else` clause, instead of `showStatus(0)`.

```
else {
    $("#status div").hide();
}
```

Comment: You were already checking for empty input with `.length`, so use that.

Comment: This is embarrassing.. Thanks for the help tho!